# New-IISSiteBinding says website does not exist, while it does

Tags: powershell, iis

For a project I'm working on I want to export IIS bindings and then import them back using PowerShell. The export part is working, but now I want to import the IIS site bindings back into IIS. I'm using the `New-IISSiteBinding` command in order to import them like this:

```
New-IISSiteBinding -Name "Portal" -BindingInformation "*:443:domainname.com" -CertificateThumbPrint "theactualthumbprint" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Protocol https
```

When running the command it says `WARNING: Web site 'Portal' does not exist.`. `Get-IISSite` is returning the same result. When I look in the IIS management console, I do see the site with that name.

Why is it saying that the Web site does not exist when it actually does?

Comment: What is the *actual* output of `Get-IISSite` when you run it?

Comment: The output is "WARNING: Web site 'Portal' does not exist."

Comment: Hold up, I'm running it in PowerShell ISE and I get that warning message, but when I run it in PowerShell itself it is working fine. Is there a limitation in PowerShell ISE which doesn't allow it?

Comment: Port number is usually at the end : "*.domainname.com:443"

Comment: ISE is no longer actively maintained, as people moved to VS Code PowerShell extension.

Comment: What is the actual output of `Get-IISSite` when you run it? NOT `Get-IISSiteBinding`

Answer (score 0):

It was actually PowerShell ISE that was the issue. When I executed the scripts in a separate PowerShell window it was working fine and importing the binding. I wasn't aware that ISE is [no longer actively maintained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/whats-new/what-s-new-in-the-powershell-50-ise?view=powershell-7.3), so that's probably why my command wasn't working.